# How to create, not edit, an object with a list of objects in C# MVC 4 using model binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Say I had a website where users create (and edit) video game consoles.  It has the following model.

```
VideoGameConsole:
  String name
  DateTime released
  List<VideoGames> games

VideoGame:
  String name
  DateTime released
  HttpPostedFileBase image
```

(I hope this example is simple enough.)

I'm wondering how to create such an object using model binding (not edit, I've seen a lot of solutions for rendering or editing an already existing dynamic list).  The current way seems to be the model binding only allows for you to create the VideoGameConsole with no games, then go back on the edit screen and add games.  I'm looking for a solution where the user can see the total object before creation.  At the very least, is there a name for what I'm trying to do that would make it easier to continue my own research on this?

Thanks.

Edit 1:

Two important notes that makes this even more... fun (in the Dwarf Fortress sense).

First, I've changed the model to include a `HttpPostedFileBase` for each `VideoGame` that represents an image.  So we need to be able to upload multiple files.  This doesn't make it that much more fun on its own.

Second, this needs to work without javascript (part of the userbase of our apps has javascript disabled for... *reasons*... and we can't just not support them).  This is where the real fun begins.

As for not using javascript, my partial solution to this is as follows.

When they click to add a new game, post the page back, do not save it, and then return the view model with that page offering the ability to edit the list of already added games or add a new one.  This is almost stateless, except on each post we add the image file to session (otherwise they'll have to re-add every file every time they decide to add a new game before hitting save).  Then we add javascript on top to make it so the intermediate postbacks are not needed if you have javascript enabled.

Comment: Would either an ajax or "regular" javascript based approach using something like Knockout.js work for you?

Comment: @Joe We can't because we cannot depend on Javascript.  It can only be used to enhance the base experience.

Answer (score 0):

You've got examples for editing an existing model like you say, so use that as a guide and in your create action, create and send down a non-null model to your view, with say 10, 20, 100 (whatever number suits) of your child items pre-populated, and just prevent the user adding new child items over and above what you've provided in the create view.

On postback, you can check the validity of the child items, to discard those you'll not want to keep - those that haven't been modified by the user.